# Personal price & Commercial price for Downloadable Product in Magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2

Does the Magento 2 have a possibility to show for customer on a Dynamic Downloadable Product Page a drop-down (as configurable option)  with 2 prices: price for personal use and price for commercial use? Or is it possible to do via plugin? Example of drop-down options:

$10 (for personal use)

$100 (for commercial use)

I looked in the Admin Tools at Downloadable Product settings and didn't find a way how to do this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved via **license_type** Product Attribute with 2 options (**personal_use**, **commercial_use**) & configurable product. In this case we need to create a parent configurable product, this product will have 2 child downloadable subproducts based on license_type attribute. Finally we can get a mandatory **license type** dropdown on a Product Dynamic Page
[image]